# Как безопасно подключаться к MySQL на C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, .net, ssh

Я подключаюсь к БД через код. Знаю, можно через API на PHP, но я не знаю язык, принципы написания такого API и времени нет совсем.

Меня пугает, что UserID и Password указываются непосредственно в коде. В БД есть несколько ролей: преподаватели и студенты. Не хотелось бы, чтобы один умный студент узнал данные роли преподавателя.

Почитал, погугли, узнал, что можно использовать SSH. И возник ряд вопросов:

1. SSH лишь обезопасит передачу, но данные в коде останутся в явном виде. Как их хранить, дабы при декомпиляции их было не найти?
2. Как поднять SSH? Посоветуете может манулы какие? Я попытался по некоторым видеоурокам, но всегда были ошибки, когда я пытался через Kitty или Putty открыть соединение. Ошибки даже через гугл мне не о чем не говорят.
3. Для SSH нужен внешний IP-адрес?

Если наговорил глупостей, то поправьте, я всего лишь как 2 часа изучаю SSH и подключение к MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Хранить учетные данные (login/pass) в коде, разумеется плохо, особенно если это самостоятельная программа, которую можно декомпилировать. Про защиту от декомпиляции уже ответили.

Есть пара довольно стандартных приемов, позволяющих не хранить учетные данные в коде программы.

1. Во время запуска программы запрашиваем у пользователя его персональные учетные данные для подключения к базе. Это наиболее легкий путь, и никакие данные, кроме технической информации вроде адреса сервера и имени базы хранить не нужно. Из минусов - необходимость создавать и настраивать для каждого пользователя учетную запись на сервере БД, ну и с ролями тоже не все так просто, т.к. вы можете настроить права на выполнение операций с базой, но к вашему приложению и ролям это придется прибивать шурупами.
2. Использовать учетную запись сервера БД с максимально ограниченными правами для подключения и авторизации. После того как учетные данные пользователя проверены и соотнесены с ролями, получить из БД подходящую для роли пользователя учетную запись сервера и использовать ее для всех остальных операций с БД. Для авторизации и получения нужных учетных данных можно написать простенькую хранимую процедуру в БД или использовать обратимое шифрование для хранения учетных данных в обычной таблице. Недостаток очевиден - более сложная система авторизации, но это компенсируется гибкостью под любые нужды вашего приложения.
3. Подключаться к базе не напрямую, а через WCF-сервис, например. Таким образом вся ответственность за безопасное хранение учетных данных сервера ложится на сервис, который живет на сервере и, в свою очередь, выступает посредником между БД и вашим приложением. Недостаток - необходимость писать сервис, достоинства - гибкость и если это именно WCF-сервис, то это делается все на том же .NET и C#.
4. Также можно применить комбинированный подход, например из пунктов 2 и 3. Приложение обращается к сервису во время авторизации, и получает от сервиса строку подключения к БД, которая соответствует роли пользователя. В этом случае у нас упрощается код сервиса из п.3 и отпадает необходимость мудрить с хранением и возвратом учетных данных сервера БД из п.2.

Возможно есть и другие способы, но, навскидку, вспомнились только эти.

Answer (score 3):

1. SSH это Secure Shell Protokol, который обычно используется для управления терминальными серверами. Конечно, через какое-то хитро выкрученное место, вы сможете сконфигурировать подключение через SSH, но это, скорее всего, не то, что вам надо. SSH может скорее пригодится для управления сервером MySQL, хотя можно и для шифрования использовать, но это сложно... Для шифрования трафика проще использовать SSL. Для этого надо будет сконфигурировать сам сервер MySQL соответсвующим образом. [Вот инструкция.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html)
2. Если уж вы всё таки решили поднять SSH, то проще всего для этого использовать Linux, куда и установить MySQL сервер. В Linux SSH, это его душа, можно сказать. [Вот инструкция для самого простого (на мой взгляд) дистрибутива.](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SSH/)
3. Зависит от того, откуда вы собираетесь получать доступ к вашему SSH серверу. Если из локальной сети, то не нужен, если через интернет, то нужен.

Но по сути всё это не решает ваших проблем. Вы хотите интерагировать с базой данных, пароли от которой хотите "захардкодить". Это не PHP и код вашей программы, как и пароли, без некоторых навыков студенты не откроют. Для этого им хотя бы придётся узнать что такое декомпилятор и как им пользоваться.

Но всё же вопрос интересный, а как таки защититься от такого рода проблем? На мой взгляд один из самых простых способов защиты это запись данных о соединении в App.config (или Web.config, если это веб-проект) и шифровка эти данных. [Вот тут вот пример как шифровать App.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file), а [тут официальная инструкция от Microsoft, по защите Connection Strings в веб проктах.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx)

Так же можете погуглить на тему обфускации кода. [Тут есть список обфускаторов для .NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET) Ещё один минус, это то, что код программы разбухает в разы. К примеру я написал тестовую программку:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   using System;

   public class Program
   {
      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var Login = "admin";
        var Passwort = "Password";

        var test = Login + ":" + Passwort;

        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Скомпилированная программа "весит" 5кб. Пропустив её через обфускатор confuserEx с настроеным шифрованием констант я получил 53кб. Декомпилятор больше не мог открыть данный файл вообще.

При некоторых настройках файл рос до 46кб и код изменялся до неузнаваемости... В декомпилированной программе я не смог больше найти указанных в коде констант.

Для декомпиляции я пользовался dotPeek от фирмы JetBrains. А вот файл-проекта обфускатора:

```
<project outputDir="C:\Dev\Test\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Obfuscated" baseDir="C:\Dev\Test\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release" xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
   <rule pattern="true" preset="maximum" inherit="false">
     <protection id="constants" />
   </rule>
   <module path="ConsoleApplication1.exe" />
</project>
```

Comment: За ссылки спасибо!

Comment: Я тут дополнил пример с обфускатором. В принципе, по скорости реализации данного решения вам этот метод подходит больше всех. 20 минут от силы и уже ваше студенты не могут декомпилировать код без глубоких знаний...